# NO MAPPING FOUND IN SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a simple spring boot app when i try to hit the endpoint http://localhost:9094/kan/echo am getting the below exception please help me resolve it o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping for GET
    i have attached the controller class and pom.xml file can anyone help me out

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/kan")
public class TestController {

     @GetMapping(value = "/echo", produces = {"application/json"})
    public List<Employee> fetch(){
        List<Employee> tempEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee emp1= new Employee();
        emp1.setName("emp1");
        emp1.setDesignation("manager");
        emp1.setEmpId("1");
        emp1.setSalary(3000);
        tempEmployees.add(emp1);
        return tempEmployees;
    }

    }
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>javainuse</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootHelloWorld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### properties file

server.port=9094

project structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXCzm.png

Comment: please have a look at the properties file, maybe you have context-path value specified there !

Comment: i dont have properties file

Comment: So where you have mentioned your boot application port: 9094?

Comment: @kanda Have you set your server port 9094 in your **application.properties** ?

Comment: server.port=9094 i have added only this and not the context path in the properties file

Comment: @kanda Can you post your **application.properties** file ?

Comment: @kanda After setting **server.port=9094** in **application.properties** are you still getting error?

Comment: yes @AvijitBarua

Comment: @kanda Can you give a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: yes  sure @AvijitBarua

Comment: @kanda, Wait I am putting an answer.

Comment: Did you want a `RestController`? Spring is expecing a view for this page.

Comment: how to resolve this @BoristheSpider i just want to create a end point

Comment: @kanda Can you let me know about your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your project structure, I think you are facing an error because of the misplacement of your main class. your project structure should be like

```
src/main/java
    |-com.kanda
          |-javainuse(package)
               |-TestController.java
          |-model(package)
               |-Employee.java
          SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java
```

In you project first create a package `com.kanda` where you put `javainuse`,`model` and your main class `SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java`. And in inner package put your controller and model class. In springboot it is require to put main class in main 
package.

updated project structure  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORAgl.png

Comment: @kanda Can you try removing **@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")**  in your controller ?

Comment: @kanda  Give a screenshot of current project structure please

Comment: updated project structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORAgl.png

Comment: @kanda , Oh man, **javainuse** and **model** will be also inside **com.java**  package

Comment: @kanda like this structure https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+project+structure&client=ubuntu&hs=l9O&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL4enr8aLlAhWi73MBHX1aBkAQ_AUIESgB&biw=1525&bih=715#imgrc=2F9T08zHzrGI-M:

Comment: @kanda Got expected result?